# When do fringe patterns disappear in this question?

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment

So, this is the question: In the Young's double hole experiment, interference fringes are formed using sodium light which predominantly compromises of two wavelengths (5890 A and 5896 A). Obtain the regions on the screen where the fringe patterns will disappear. You may assume d = 0.5 mm and D = 100 cm.
Now, I have a couple of doubts regarding the solution (I guess most of them are conceptual doubts). Firstly, how do we have two different wavelengths? Isn't the experiment possible only if we have one single light source with one particular wavelength? Secondly, the solution says that the fringes disappear when the fringes of the two wavelengths coincide. Why is that? And lastly, the solution says that to solve this question, we'll end up with this equation: n<sub>1</sub>$\lambda$<sub>1</sub> = (n<sub>2</sub>+1/2)$\lambda$<sub>2</sub>. Here, the solution told us to assume that n<sub>1</sub> = n<sub>2</sub>. How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most prominent transitions in terms of intensity of spectral lines for excited sodium atoms are shown below.  There are many other transitions which occur but the resulting spectral lines are much less intense.

[image]

The condition for a maximum of intensity is $n\,\lambda = d\, \sin \theta_{\rm n}$, where $n$ is the order of the fringe, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light, $d$ is the separation of the holes and $\theta_{\rm n}$ is the angle measured relative to the straight through path.

[image]

Assume the two wavelengths are  $\lambda_1 = 5896\, \rm A$ and  $\lambda_2 = 5890\, \rm A$.

For both wavelengths the $n=0$ fringe maxima coincide.

For the $n=1$ fringes the $\lambda_1$ maximum is **slightly** further from the $n=0$ maximum as compared with the $\lambda_2$ maximum.

As the order increases the separation between the maxima increases until the $n$ maximum for wavelength $\lambda_1$ coincides with the $n+1/2$ minimum for wavelength $\lambda_2$ and that being so, no fringes are visible.

Continuing on there will come a position such the $n'$ maximum for wavelength $\lambda_1$ coincides with the $n'+1$ maximum for wavelength $\lambda_2$ and that being so the visibility of the fringes is again maximized.

The arrangement described in the question using two holes is unlikely to be realised in practice.
However one can show the extinction and reappearance of the fringes using a Newton's rings arrangement or an interferometer as the images below show.

[image]

**1** would be around the $n=0$ fringes, **5** shows the extinction when the maximum of one fringe pattern coincides with a minimum of the other fringe pattern, and **8** shows the maxima of the two fringe patterns coinciding but b=differing by one order.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have 2 different wavelengths because you are using a Sodium light source, and the 2 wavelengths correspond to the hyperfine levels of the ground state (ie. when the Sodium is excited to an excited state it can decay to one of 2 ground states that have a very small difference in energy.)

The experiment is possible with any wavelength distribution.  The issue interpretation of the results.  The fringe spacing is ~λ (the wavelength).  So, you'll have 2 sets of fringes corresponding to the 2 different wavelengths, but their respective offset will be very small close to the center of the pattern.

2. The interference will "disappear" (ie. the contrast will be less strong) as you move away from the center of the screen, and at some point the contrast may be zero depending on the particular geometry.

This is best understood by plotting two sine waves, Sin (x), and Sin (x+ delta), for small delta.  After several periods the peak of one Sin will overlap the minimum of the other.  When you add them together you'll get zero.

Comment: Alright, that explains it well. But, one doubt still remains. Why did we assume both the n's to be equal in that equation? Like, how do we know for sure the n at which these fringe patterns will coincide will exactly be the same?

Comment: The 'n's refer to the order, or period number, of the sine waves.  Again, if you make that plot of the sines and follow them out for large 'n' you'll find that the first place they are out of phase is when n1=n2.  It'll happen again but much later and then the n's will be different.

Comment: And one last doubt... You said that the two fringes cancel each other out. And the condition is, des. interference of one wavelength should coincide with the constructive of the other. But, destructive interference would just give us y = 0, while constructive interference gives us something of the form: 2acos(theta). So, how do they cancel each other out?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'y' or 'theta' is.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just a few conventions the textbook was using. y is basically the final wave equation after the combination of the waves from the two pins. theta is omega*time

Comment: @JQK The graphs that should be drawn are $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin^2(x+\delta)$.

Comment: @Farcher It doesn't matter.  The conclusion is the same.